# Remove item in std::list while leaving it allocated

Tags: c++, stl, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I build a `std::list` of items (graph component structures) which are periodically merged together. The idea is if I discover a node connecting two components they become one single component and my list enumerates my components. Each component has a handle (in this case an `std::list<component>::iterator`) to its "parent" component which is set once it gets merged. This way to determine the component a particular node belongs to I walk up this chain.

In the end what I'm looking for is the operation on `std::list` which allows me to take an iterator of item `N`, and *remove* it from the list but without deallocating it: the structure of the rest of the list is modified in exactly the same way as removing it normally.

Preferably something less ugly than re-allocating the item, copying it from the list, and calling the real `remove` or `erase`.

Perhaps I can accomplish it with `splice`. I'd need to splice the elements to be removed into a "junk" `list`, don't I?

Comment: `splice`-ing into a _junk list_ sounds about right...

Comment: And such an approach has the unlikely possibility that the use of incompatible allocators would force copying. Still... theres a few extra pointers getting shuffled. Well... doesn't *hurt* to have a way to iterate over my not-fully-orphaned nodes.

Comment: Why using list<component *> instead of list<component> is not suitable for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with splice. For example, move `*it` to junk list:

```
junk.splice(junk.begin(),comp_list,it);
```

You can also add move-ctor to `component`.  Then, before erasing from list move contents to tmp var, something like this:

```
component  tmp(*it);
li.erase(it);
```

Also suggestion of Fomin Arseniy  to use list of pointers to components (or `std::shared_ptr`) is good too.

Comment: a plain `list<T*>` is likely to result in more manual bookkeeping than necessary, but `list<shared_ptr<T> >` is probably a solid approach as well. I wanted to keep things simple: with the junk list approach I can avoid writing the `new` keyword.